# Does all methods of HttpClient internally invoke SendAsync method?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, httpclient, sendasync, getasync

Does all methods of `HttpClient` i.e. `GetAsync`, `PostAsync` etc. internally invoke `SendAsync` method?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Why are you asking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the [`HttpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) uses an [`HttpMessageHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpmessagehandler(v=vs.118).aspx) underneath to perform all HTTP requests. The `HttpMessageHandler` method [`Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage, CancellationToken)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpmessagehandler.sendasync(v=vs.118).aspx) is what is called by the `HttpClient`.

The default implementation of the abstract class `HttpMessageHandler` is [`HttpClientHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclienthandler(v=vs.118).aspx).

[You can pass in your own `HttpMessageHandler` implementation to the `HttpClient` constructor that takes one.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193664(v=vs.118).aspx) Although it's highly unlikely you'd ever need to, there are applications. For example, if you wanted to log every request your `HttpClient` makes. You could make a `LoggingHttpMessageHandler` decorator for a `HttpMessageHandler`.

```
using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler())
using (var loggingHandler = new LoggingHttpClientHandler(handler, logger))
using (var client = new HttpClient(loggingHandler))
{
    // Logs "GET https://www.google.com/"
    var response = await client.GetAsync("https://www.google.com/");
    ...
}
```

Comment: Does this still apply to dotnet core 6?